# how do i auto fill cells based on conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I need to auto fill a cell based on if 2 cells contain specific values and then auto run it. This is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If target.Cells(5, "B").Value = "Secured" And target.Cells(6, "B").Value = "Amendment" Then
        Cells(10, "B") = "T2 - Medium Risk"
    End If

End Sub
```

The if statement would be `=IF(AND(D34="Secured",D35="Amendment"),"yes","")` but the "yes" need to be in a different cell

Comment: If you need D34 and B34, you should change `.Cells(5,"B")` and `.Cells(6,"B")` to `.Cells(34,"D")` and `.Cells(35,"D")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:B6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Cells(5, 2) = "Secured" And Cells(6, 2) = "Amendment" Then
            Cells(10, 2) = "T2 - Medium Risk"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You want it to fire when the change is within those two cells and if they match, then populate a different cell. If you want to erase it, you can do that too.